# OpenCV,C++: Missing Triangles in Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, triangulation, delaunay

I am using NetBeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 and would like to obtain triangles from a set of points using OpenCV. I build the Delaunay triangulation as follows.

```
vector< Triangle > CTwoDTriangulation::delaunayDiv(const vector< Point_<T> > & vP,   cv::Rect boundRect, vector<Triangle>& triangles, int& numTriangles)
{
    CvSubdiv2D* subdiv;
    int numPts=vP.size();
    CvPoint newPoint;

    CvMemStorage *storage;
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    subdiv =  cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D( boundRect, storage );
    for (size_t e = 0; e<numPts; e++)
    {
        newPoint=vP.at(e);
        if (newPoint.x>=boundRect.y && newPoint.y>=boundRect.y && newPoint.x<boundRect.width &&  newPoint.y<boundRect.height)
                cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(subdiv, vP.at(e));
    }

    CvSeqReader  reader;
    int i, total = subdiv->edges->total;
    int elem_size = subdiv->edges->elem_size;

    triangles.resize(2*total-5);    // Maximum number of triangles for number of edges
    numTriangles=0;

    cvStartReadSeq( (CvSeq*)(subdiv->edges), &reader, 0 );

    Triangle V;

    for( i = 0; i < total; i++ )
    {
        CvQuadEdge2D* edge = (CvQuadEdge2D*)(reader.ptr);

        if( CV_IS_SET_ELEM( edge ))
        {
            CvSubdiv2DEdge e = (CvSubdiv2DEdge)edge;
            if (FindTriangleFromEdge(e, V)) 
        {
            triangles.at(numTriangles++)=V;
        }
    }
    CV_NEXT_SEQ_ELEM( elem_size, reader );
}
cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);

return triangles;
}
```

FindTriangleFromEdge() has the following form.

```
void CTwoDTriangulation::FindTriangleFromEdge(CvSubdiv2DEdge e, Triangle& V)
{
   CvSubdiv2DEdge t = e;    // Number of type size_t
   CvPoint buf[3];          // Triangle vertices
   int iPointNum = 3;
   int  j;
   CvPoint pts[3];

   for(j = 0; j < iPointNum; j++ )
   {
        CvSubdiv2DPoint* point = cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg( t );
        if( !point ) break;
        pts[j].x=point->pt.x;
        pts[j].y=point->pt.y;
        buf[j] = cvPoint( cvRound(point->pt.x), cvRound(point->pt.y));
        t = cvSubdiv2DGetEdge( t, CV_NEXT_AROUND_LEFT );
   }
  AddTriangle(buf, pts, V);
}
```

This gets me most of the triangles but some are missing.  For example, I set a set of points that approximate a rectangular grid.  I get the following
(5,1);(103,101);(1,101)
(106,1);(103,101);(5,1)
(5,1);(106,1);(103,101)
(204,101);(106,1);(208,1)
(208,1);(307,101);(204,101)
(309,1);(307,101);(204,101)

So (106,1);(204,1);(103,101)is missing and at least one triangle is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement seems to have a bug? Why are you comparing newPoint.x with boundRect.y?

```
if (newPoint.x>=boundRect.y && newPoint.y>=boundRect.y && newPoint.x<boundRect.width &&  newPoint.y<boundRect.height)
            cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(subdiv, vP.at(e));
```

Comment: I think that's it. Also, could it be that @OtagoHarbour needs the last two compares to be newPoint.x<(boundRect.x + boundRect.width) &&  newPoint.y<(boundRect.y + boundRect.height)?

Comment: Yup, seems he needs that as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for noticing that.  Unfortunately, boundRect.x and boundRect.y are the same so that is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks @emsr.  I made that change but still have the problem.  The offending triangles are mainly surrounded by other triangles so I do not think it wold be a boundary effect.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to check against

cvSubdiv2DGetEdge( t, CV_NEXT_AROUND_RIGHT );

and look! with this it found the missing ones, but misses some others. So my solution is to combine both results for now.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `CV_NEXT_AROUND_LEFT` the next edge to be chosen will be the one on LEFT facet of the specified edge. Now consider, for example, a triangle formed by vertices `V1`, `V2` and `V3`, whose sides are `Edge1`, `Edge2` and `Edge3`.

Additionally, imagine that `V1` is the Org Point of `Edge1`, `V2` is the Org Point of `Edge2` and `V3` is the Org Point of `Edge3` (like vectors connected in a clockwise orientation).  In this case, the left facets are always outside the given triangle so, in your code, this triangle will be missing.

I could not realize another way of preventing this except by combining `CV_NEXT_AROUND_LEFT` with `CV_NEXT_AROUND_RIGHT` and removing the duplicate triangles that will be recorded.